# Where does the JSON schema for this IntelliJ inspection live?

Tags: json, intellij-idea, yaml, jsonschema

Where is the JSON schema for this inspection live?

[image]

Comment: I would imagine it validates against any `$schema` directives in the file

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/json.html#ws_json_using_schemas
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/json.html#ws_json_schema_add_custom